# Obtain elements from a list with a for loop

Tags: list, r, for-loop

I am trying to extract values from a list using a forloop. The list contains 77 elements that I have scraped from a webpage. They were put into a list with strsplit matched to a rather messy regular expression.

```
chunk <- strsplit(lines, "(<tr>|</td>)(<td>|<td[^>]+>)|aws| MB| KB")
```

A sample element looks like:

```
> chunk[76]
[[1]]
 [1] ""                                                                                     
 [2] "<img src=\"/images/"                                                                  
 [3] "tats/flags/mn.png\" height=\"14\" alt='mn' title='mn' />"                             
 [4] "Mongolia"                                                                             
 [5] "mn"                                                                                   
 [6] "1"                                                                                    
 [7] "1"                                                                                    
 [8] "21.95"                                                                                
 [9] ""                                                                                     
[10] "<img src=\"/images/"                                                                  
[11] "tats/other/hp.png\" width=\"2\" height=\"5\" alt='Pages: 1' title='Pages: 1' /><br />"
```

I have tried to extract the parts of each elements that I need with:

```
for (i in length(chunk)) {  
    values <- chunk[[i]][c(4,6:8)]
}
```

The result returned for values is always the extracted parts of the last list element `(chunk[[77]])`

Can anyone suggest how to obtain the values I need for every list element.

Comment: Instead of regexpr, using e.g. xpath from XML package could be an option if you parse HTML pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lapply` with `do.call(rbind, ...)` instead of the for loop.

```
chunk <- list(
  c("", "<img src=\"/images/",
  "tats/flags/mn.png\" height=\"14\" alt='mn' title='mn' />",
  "Mongolia", "mn", "1", "1", "21.95", "", "<img src=\"/images/",
  "tats/other/hp.png\" width=\"2\" height=\"5\" alt='Pages: 1' title='Pages: 1' /><br />"),
  c("", "<img src=\"/images/",
  "tats/flags/mn.png\" height=\"14\" alt='mn' title='mn' />",
  "Mongolia", "mn", "1", "1", "21.95", "", "<img src=\"/images/",
  "tats/other/hp.png\" width=\"2\" height=\"5\" alt='Pages: 1' title='Pages: 1' /><br />") )
do.call(rbind, lapply(chunk, `[`, c(4,6:8)))
#      [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4]   
# [1,] "Mongolia" "1"  "1"  "21.95"
# [2,] "Mongolia" "1"  "1"  "21.95"
```

Comment: I see what you mean Joris/Joshua.  `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(chunk, `[`, c(4,6:8))))` gives the desired output without a forloop. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should replace `values <- chunk[[i]][c(4,6:8)]` with `values <- rbind(values,chunk[[i]][c(4,6:8)])` (initialize `values <- NULL` before the loop).

Or you can create a matrix before the loop `values <- matrix(0,length(chunk),4)` and in the loop use `values[i,] <- chunk[[i]][c(4,6:8)]`. This is more efficient!

Comment: Beauty, it should have read values <- matrix(0,length(chunk),4) for the second answer but this is what worked. I appreciate your time and advice.

Comment: You should get rid of the for-loop altogether.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise to use Perl instead. It is much more handy in performing the operations (I assume) you would like to do.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I am not sure I have time to take on Perl. I am trying to learn Python alongside R and probably do not have time for Perl as well.

Comment: Why the downvotes??? I faced the same problem a year ago and started using Perl instead which enabled me to do a lot more.

Comment: @John I now it is time consuming to keep learning new languages. However, for the above task you will find Perl to be a darling. Happy coding! Christian

Comment: I did not downvote but I would suspect it is because it did not answer the question or offer a workable solution.

Comment: Is it required to only give workable solutions in terms of cut-and-paste-code? I am new to SO - still trying to figure out what to do and what not to do :-)

Comment: @Christian : part is also that your claim is simply not true. I do know and use perl, but you clearly underestimate the power of R. Perl has some serious drawbacks when working with vectors and matrices, even when talking string work.